# Etymologically, does the "pro-" in "procreo" have a specific referrant?

Tags: etymology

What is the etymology of [*procreo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=procreo)? How does it differ from [*creo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=procreo)? Does the "*pro-*" in [*procreo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=procreo) refer to someone or something specific—e.g., to God or country, in the sense that procreation is for the sake of God or for a nation ([*natio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=la&l=natio) = birth)?

According to the [*OED*](https://oed.com/view/Entry/151869), the earliest English usage of "procreate" is in the context of begetting children for God:

> a1525   in W. A. Craigie *Asloan MS* (1923) I. 301/2   Adam of iij<sup>c</sup> & xxx<sup>ti</sup> ȝeris procreat Seth of quhom com the sonnis of God.
> <sub>[Adam of 130 years procreated Seth of whom come the sons of God.]</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Nothing to do with the purpose, even though *prō* (as a preposition) generally shows purpose. Weird, isn't it?

Latin really likes to stick prepositional prefixes on verbs; sometimes these change the meaning in predictable ways (*ob-* makes the action intentional), sometimes they make idioms you wouldn't expect (*per-eō* "through" + "go" = polite word for "die"), but most of the time **they just make the verb more intense**.

That's what's happening here. *Creō* and *prōcreō* mean the same thing, but the latter puts more emphasis on it.

Comment: Can't "_pro-_" also mean "toward" or "forward" like "process" (vs. "recess") or "progress"? It seems it's not just an intensifier or something regarding purpose.

Comment: @Geremia "It seems it's not just an intensifier"…why?

Comment: Do you have any evidence to support your claim that "_pro-_" here has "Nothing to do with the purpose"? And what is it about _procreo_ that is "more intense" than _creo_?

Comment: @Geremia Mostly, Lewis and Short don't mention any sense of purpose, none of the examples I've found show a sense of purpose, and while it's hard to prove a negative, the fact that Cicero and Lucretius seem to use it as a plain intensifier is pretty solid evidence imo.

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting a certain answer and don't want any other; do you have evidence that it *does* have something to do with "for the sake of God"?

Comment: (As far as "more intense": that's just what verbal prefixes generally do in Latin. They put more emphasis on the verb, emphasizing the begetting or creating or producing or whatever.)

Comment: I added an _OED_ quote. Also, "procreate" in English is something restricted to humans; we don't say animals reproduce, not procreate.

Comment: @Geremia Oh, in English the meanings are totally different, yeah ("create" and "procreate" are far from synonymous). I'm talking solely about the meanings in Latin; it's worth noting that Gen 4:25 in the Vulgate uses the unrelated verb _pariō_ instead of _prōcreō_.

Comment: It's not just Latin. Slavonic languages, and to an extent Germanic ones, use a variety of preverbs that seem to be originally directional in a wide variety of senses. Consider _understand_, _withhold_ and _forbear_.

Comment: @ColinFine I understand Draconis to only be referring to this particular word. Some words have what's called "intensifiers", prefixes that just strengthen the word (although not always even that, especially when they're used in vulgar speech). Other times, of course, the prefix will substantially alter the meaning. It's always on a case-by-case basis.

Answer (score 4):

The linguistic meanings of *creare* and *procreare* are not the same: the latter contains a directional prefix, which indeed has a semantic contribution that goes beyond the meaning of 'in front of'. For example, according to García-Hernández, a Spanish Latinist scholar who has analyzed the very complex topic of Latin preverbs, *pro-* enters into an important opposition with *ob-*: e.g., vid. García-Hernández (1991): [*pro-* vs. *ob-*](https://books.google.es/books?id=2WdGEJF3A2YC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=garc%C3%ADa%20hernandez%20prefijos%20ob%20pro&source=bl&ots=ga6Q6MEgPF&sig=ACfU3U3MP7_RF3sPWTcdfAZjNeuTt2ZzDg&hl=ca&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwidrqXptabiAhViUBUIHWeYA_EQ6AEwDHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=garc%C3%ADa%20hernandez%20prefijos%20ob%20pro&f=false). In particular, I like his image-schematic representation of Latin preverbs.

It is well-known that the path/directional meaning of Latin preverbs became grammaticalized into other more abstract notions (e.g., aspect; cf. also the "intensive" value attributed by Draconis in his answer). It is worth pointing out that, in the specialized literature, complex/prefixed verbs like *procreare* or *producere* are considered as good examples of the so-called "satellite-framed" nature of Latin: path/directionality (and aspect) is typically encoded in the preverb or particle (aka. "satellite") in so-called "satellite-framed languages" (e.g., Early & Classical Latin, German, Russian, etc.), whereas it is typically expressed in the verbal root in so-called "verb-framed languages" (e.g., Catalan, Spanish, Turkish, Japanese, etc.).

Accordingly, a typical linguistic analysis of Latin complex verbs like *procreare* involves (i) to consider the preverb *pro-* as the so-called "framing event", i.e., as the main predicate and (ii) to consider the verbal root as the so-called "co-event", i.e., as the subordinate predicate. So ***procreare* (originally) means** something like **"to bring forth by creating"**. In contrast, the meaning of *creare* is obviously less complex since it lacks the path/aspectual meaning attributed to the prefix.

For readers interested in this complex topic of Latin linguistics, here is a recent reference: [Latin as a satellite-framed language](https://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198733287.001.0001/acprof-9780198733287-chapter-4). Among other interesting things, this author shows a very important parallelism between Latin and Slavic languages (both are classified as "satellite-framed languages" in Talmy's famous typology: [A typology of event conflation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a687/50b28a6c9cd922e9070e5a2945e7b90f4130.pdf)). Typically, when dealing with verbal prefixation in Latin and Slavic, the prefix expresses the main semantic idea, whereas the verbal root expresses the subordinate one (something similar to the English "out-prefixation construction": e.g., *John {outran/outdanced/outdrank/outworked/...} Mary*; lit.,'John surpassed Mary by V-ing' (cf. the lexical subordination meaning of *procreare* above). As noted above, this is also quite typical of other satellite-framed languages like Russian (e.g., see https://www.researchgate.net/publication/248315875_Verb_prefixation_in_Russian_as_lexical_subordination ).

Comment: Satellite-framed languages = 'float-into' or 'in-float' languages. In contrast, "verb-framed languages" = 'enter-floating' languages. Latin (like Russian) belongs to the first type, whereas Catalan and other Romance languages belong to the second type. Notice that it is a good example that shows that a **typological** classification of languages can be quite different from a **genetic** one.

Answer (score -1):

Since an individual of a species cannot be the cause of that species (otherwise a human, e.g., would be the cause of himself), it procreates as an instrument of a higher agent (cf. [*Summa Contra Gentiles* lib. 2 cap. 21](https://isidore.co/aquinas/ContraGentiles2.htm#21) nn. 5 & 8).

So, "pro-" in "procreate" most likely means "for" in sense [2a](https://oed.com/view/Entry/151666#eid28459148): "**instead of**", as in "proconsul" or "pronoun".

A procreating being is an instrument of a higher agent (e.g., God for humans, the natural environment for brute animals). The higher agent acts "instead of" the individual/instrument.

Comment: Downvoter, please explain why you down-voted

Comment: Going to hazard a guess, but perhaps it is because you explain the term in context of Christianity, but the word *procreare* is also found in Plautus, Cicero, and Lucretius, so it can hardly have that monotheistic meaning you ascribe (and doesn't seem to be in reference to gods in those passages). L&S's note is informative: "[pro-'s] signification has reference either to place, before, forwards; or to protection, for; procedo, procurro, profanus; procuro, propugno, prosum, protego."